# (Xcode 8, Swift 3, Alamofire 4.0) Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm getting this error and I don't know how to solve it. I've searched in this forum too, but nothing help me to solve my problem. Here is the code that get me that error:

```
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:NSDictionary) ->  (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) { //URLRequestConvertible
    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
    mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    //let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345"
    let boundaryConstant = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()
    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        if value is NetData {
            // add image
            let postData = value as! NetData
            // append content disposition
            let filenameClause = " filename=\"\(postData.filename)\""
            let contentDispositionString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\";\(filenameClause)\r\n"
            let contentDispositionData = contentDispositionString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            uploadData.append(contentDispositionData!)
            // append content type
            let contentTypeString = "Content-Type: \(postData.mimeType.getString())\r\n\r\n"
            let contentTypeData = contentTypeString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            uploadData.append(contentTypeData!)
            uploadData.append(postData.data as Data)
        }else{
            uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
    }
    uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (try Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.encode(mutableURLRequest as! ParameterEncoding) as! URLRequestConvertible, uploadData)

}
```

But If I remove:

```
try Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.encode(mutableURLRequest as! ParameterEncoding) as! URLRequestConvertible
```

And set the return value as NSData only, the error is gone. The problem is I need to return URLRequestConvertible too. So, what should I do?

Update:
If I remove "as! URLRequestConvertible" it's getting me another error:

```
Cannot invoke value of type '(ParameterEncoding) -> (URLRequestConvertible, Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest' with argument list '(ParameterEncoding)'
```

Comment: Hello Have you found a solution please?

Comment: @Sam No, I haven't found any solution for that problem, so I use httprequest method instead of Alamofire.